# Retornar fecha actual con php y que ésta no se actualice nunca más

Tags: date

Quiero que una funcion me retorne la fecha actual, pero, una vez que lo haga, que no se cambie nunca mas (que no sea dinamica).

Es para una pagina de noticias. Cada vez que cree un articulo no quiero estar poniendo la fecha manualmnete, por eso usare una funcion que me retorne la fecha actual. El problema es que cada vez que recargue la web la fecha cambiara (por ejemplo los dias siguientes tendra la fecha de ese dia, y no del dia de la publicacion), y no quiero que pase eso. Quiero que se quede para siempre la fecha del dia que publique, y que no cambie para nadie (no quiero que retorne la fecha actual el dia que un usuario nuevo entre a mi pagina y la recargue, quiero que mantenga la fecha del dia que yo publique). Con javascript no puedo hacer eso.

¿Alguien me ayuda por favor con un codigo resumido y sencillo?

Comment: Yo gestionaría ese contenido en una base de datos donde se guarden los diferentes elementos, la fecha de publicación de la noticia incluida, algo al estilo Wordpress.

Answer (score 2):

Si entiendo bien lo que haces realmente es ir creando los archivos propios de forma manual en php donde vas escribiendo cada noticia.

Podrías usar la función getlastmod() que te da una marca de tiempo unix de la última modificación del archivo y le puedes dar formato con la función date por ejemplo:

```
echo "Ultima modificación: ".date("d-m-Y", getlastmod());
```

Prueba a ver si te funciona.

Comment: Xavi. Creo que esto si funciona! Lo he probado cambiadole el D M Y por S (para ver los segundos), y cuando hago eso, el segundo deja de actualizarse cuando recargo la web. Probe en otros navegadores y sigue manteniendo el cambio inicial. Creo que si funciona.  ¿Me podes explicar mejor de que se trata esa funcion? es que no me gusta tener un codigo que no entiendo. No se mucho de php, solo lo basico. Gracias.

Comment: @eduardo Todo sistema operativo guarda metadatos sobre los archivos (datos sobre datos), por listar algunos: fecha de creación, última modificación y permisos de archivo. La función `getlastmod()` es una función nativa de php (escrita en C), el cuál pregunta directamente al sistema operativo (a través de su propia API)  cuándo fue la última vez que se modificó el archivo. Mientras el archivo no se modifique entonces `getlastmod` devolverá siempre el mismo valor, eso está garantizado por el propio sistema operativo, saludos

Comment: Entonces te parece bien esta funcion como alternativa momentanea? (hasta que aprenda base de datos). O sea te explico brevemente como es.

Comment: tengo un ARTICLE, con un H1 (donde va mi titulo), un P (donde va mi parrafo) y abajo un DIV (donde va mi fecha).. ahi quiero meter una funcion que me retorne la fecha actual (para yo no tener que ponerla manualmente) pero que una vez retornada no cambie... ¿ahi, en mi DIV, deberia colocar el ECHO date (getlastmod),   cierto?

Comment: Y si altero algo del HTML que no tenga que ver con PHP ¿cuenta como ultima modificacion, o solo cuentan los cambios en php? (no se si se entiende esto que quiero decir)

Comment: @eduardo El sistema operativo asegura la integridad del archivo, es decir que agregar un simple salto de línea o modificar/eliminar un caracter será considerado como una modificación. El sistema operativo le importa poco si el archivo contiene HTML, HTML & PHP, o cualquiera que sea la interpretación semántica del archivo, siempre será tratado como un flujo de bytes, cualquier byte eliminado/modifcado/agregado será considerado como modificación.

Comment: @eduardo Mi consejo es que el artículo no lleve HTML ni PHP, si no texto plano, así si modificas el archivo será el contenido del artículo y no algo referente al marcado. Otras opciones viables sería el guardar metadatos sobre los articulos y programar un gestor de artículos que se encargue de actualizar los metadatos a partir de la lógica del negocio.

Comment: @eduen  Entonces tendre un problema con eso. ¿por que? pues porque, dentro de mi documento HTML tengo dos require, para el header y footer, y entonces, cuando haga cambios del menu que esta en el header, o del footer, la fecha de mi articulo cambiara ¿me explico?

Comment: @eduen  es decir, el header y footer estan en documetnos php aparte (headerPHP y footerPHP), y en mi documento principal (indexPHP) llamo con require a mi header y footer.

Comment: @eduen ahora, si alguna vez hago un cambio del menu, aunque sea desde otro documento (headerPHP), la fecha de mi articulo (que esta en mi pagina principal donde usare la funcion getlastmod) se alterara supongo, segun lo que te he entendido

Comment: @eduardo No habrá ningún problema en tu caso expuesto. El sistema operativo no entiende PHP, le da lo mismo un "require", que un "hola" o "12341235", es decir, que no ejecutará el código PHP (abrir el documento expuesto en require, fusionar archivos, devolver la fusión de ambos, e interpretar el código). Mientras no modifiques el artículo en sí, no habrá problema, puedes modificar *headerPHP* y *footerPHP* sin que por ello cambie la fecha de última modificación.

Comment: @eduen Entiendo. Ya hice la prueba y tenes razón. Cuando hago un  cambio en el mismo documento index.php donde tengo ejecutada la funcion lastmod, la fecha se actualiza, pero, si le hago el cambio al header o footer que son documentos externos incrustados con un require, no modifica la fecha.

Comment: @eduen SUpongo que por ahora esto es lo mas perfecto que puedo conseguir, y te agradezco. He visto que hay otra funcion llamada FILETIME ¿me dices por favor cual es la diferencia con LASTMOD? por la descripcion parecen iguales.

Comment: @eduen asi lo he puesto: <p> <?php echo date( 'd M Y', getlastmod(  ) ) ?> </p>...... ¿esta bien? en ese parrafo insertaba la fecha manuamente (el parrafo va al pie de mi articulo)

Comment: @eduardo *getlastmod* devuelve la última modificación del archivo donde se ejecute el script, mientras que *filemtime* obtiene la última modificación de cualquier archivo. Imagina que deseas obtener la ultima modificación de *headerPHP* desde *indexPHP* entonces necesitarás usar *filemtime*. Por el contrario, si quieres saber la última modificación de *indexPHP* desde *indexPHP* puedes usar tanto *getlastmod* como *filemtime*, la diferencia radica en que *getlastmod* el archivo está implicito y no necesitarás usar ningún argumento, contrario a *filemtime* donde el archivo debe ir explícito.

Comment: @eduardo creo que eduen te lo ha explicado perfectamente. Creo que getlasmod es la solución que mas se adapta para la forma en que lo tienes montado todo. Pero sinceramente la mejor solución sería aprender a utilizar las bases de datos, piensa que sólo tendrías que montar un sólo archivo en php donde se gestionaría lo introducido en la BD y ya está, sólo ir introduciendo la información en ella, el ahorro de tiempo creo que sería bestial.

Answer (score 0):

**Buen día**

Coloca tu código y se te puede apoyar; de momento te comparto una idea para que la realices.

1. Cuando inicies sesión; de tu Base de Datos *(donde guardas las noticias)* busca la fecha más reciente y toma esa como la que utilizaras; **la guardas en variable de sesión**.
2. Este valor de la variable de sesión será la que colocaras en el dato que corresponda a la fecha.
3. Según agregues noticias tomas la fecha de la recien guardada y actualizas la variable de sesión (solo cuando sea nueva la noticia; no si es actualización).

Con lo anterior no tendrás que estar colocando cada vez la fecha; y tendrás la última más recien usada siempre y cuando claro; sea una fecha reciente; por que si agregas una noticia con la fecha de ayer (por que se te olvido agregarla...., etc) y guardar al menos una con fecha de hoy, desde luego el sistema te traera la de hoy no la de ayer.

Si tu sistema o donde registras no inicias sesión, entonces en vez de al iniciar sesión, comprueba si existe la variable de sesión y si no consultas la BD y tomas la fecha más reciente. así por el estilo las consideraciones acorde a los escenarios que se pueden presentar.

Comment: Gracias por responder... Olvidé mencionar que no estoy usando ningún gestor de contenido, sino que es mi página es a medida, por lo tanto no tengo almacenados mis artículos en una base de datos :S. Edito mis articulos en mi propio HTML y luego los subo a mi hosting. Y no quiero actualizar manualmente la fecha porque, aparte que son muchos articulos, podria equivocarme en una u olvidarme. QUiero algo como un require, por ejemplo mi header y footer estan con require, y cada cambio que hago en el documento require se aplica a todas las paginas

Comment: Te sugiero compartas al menos una parte del código que tienes, tu estrcutura como la manejas (el escenario existe que de idea idea que tienes) y en base a ello te daran sugerencias; si lo hace directamente en el HTMl sin usar administrador de contenido; personalmente no tengo de momento idea para sugerirte.

Comment: Aunque no uses CMS como Wordpress u otro, puedes implementar algo parecido. Es decir, almacenar tu contenido en una base de datos. De esa forma será mucho más cómodo manejar, actualizar, mantener, presentar los datos. Y ademas tendrás siempre tu información segura mediante copias de seguridad. Sería cuestión de tener tu plantilla de noticias y llamar allí el contenido respectivo desde la base de datos.

Comment: Si estuviera usando un gestor no haria esta pregunta, porque tengo entendido que en worpress no tienes que actualizar tú mismo la fecha. Lo que si tienes que actualizar tú mismo son las imagenes y texto.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que estas intentando plantear que por lo que entiendo es hacer noticias cada una con su archivo HTML.php, me parece una idea de los tiempos del 2000, te sugiero que aprendas Mysql o cualquier otro sistema de base de datos.

Transformar esta respuesta en un comentario. Saludos!

Comment: PWRON+ No me gusta usar gestores de contenido, prefiero las paginas a medida. Son totalmente controlables. Espero algun dia poder hacer mi propio gestor, pero nunca usare el de otros, como worpress, drupal, joomla,etc.. no me gustan.

Comment: Una base de datos no es un CMS. Todos los CMS usan bases de datos para guardar información.Y si tu idea es algún dia hacer tu propio gestor de contenido , mas te vale aprender bases de datos como MYSQL , ORACLE , etc etc etc